# Increase a variable number by 1

Tags: c, variables

I have code in which I have a large number of characters all declared as being 1 higher than the other.
e.g. m1, m2, m3...

is there any way to increase the number I'm searching for by 1 in a for loop?
I have a long string of letters that I need to check to see if any of them match to the individual, but I cannot use strings due to situational limitations.

a1 is the particular character I'm looking for, m1 is the first in a long string of characters I am having to store as individuals

My attempt that wouldn't run:

```
for (a1 != m["%d"], &check, check++)
```

Unfortunately due to the limits of my application I can only use stdio.h and stdlib.h in my solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No, you can't look up C variables by name at runtime. Use an array instead.

Comment: It would improve the question to post some actual code for context, not really clear what you mean by a `for` with no semicolons , or what `a1` and `check` are etc. etc.

Comment: ... or how the string literal `"%d"` can be used as an array index.

Comment: X Y by the sounds of it, what are you trying to do and what situaional limits do you have.

Comment: Well, if it is really necessary, mandatory, you could make a program in C that uses loops to generate another program in C where all variables are like M1, ... Mn... But other languages allow constructs made of variables-variable (like `$$x` in PHP, or in Lisp, Perl etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names are used by the compiler, but are not part of the generated executable and therefore not accessible at runtime. You can simulate something like that by an array initialized with the addresses of the respective variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a0=0,a1=10,a2=15;
    int *a[3] = { &a0, &a1, &a2 };
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      int val = *(a[i]);
      printf("a%d:%d\n",i,val);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a0:0
a1:10
a2:15
```

Comment: OP says  cannot use arrays, apparently they can